# Trouble working with Github

Tags: installation, windows-vista, github, powershell-2.0

In order to learn from other and better programmers how to write good code I decided to install Github Desktop.

It was installed-no problem, but, on opening the Git shell that comes with the installation package,it tells me PowerShell 2.0 is deprecated, and must install PowerShell 3.0.

On the Github forum I found answers which first said to go for PowerShell 3.0 but later they added a comment as to go for PowerShell 5.0 instead.

Now I did some research and found no other version except 1.0 and 2.0 work for Windows Vista.

The problem is - how am I supposed to go for PowerShell 5.0 or even 3.0?
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I decided to install Github" What exactly did you install? Github Desktop? Git for Windows? From where?

Comment: Github Desktop..I'll edit and add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the git desktop tool. Install [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest) and next [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/download/).

Go to a project site and click on the green button `download or clone` and copy the repository address.

[image]

Go to Explorer, do a rightclick on the folder where you want to clone the code, select `Git Clone`, paste the repository address and click on `ok`. This clones the repository and you can check the code, compile it on your own.

Comment: The TortoiseGit link you sent,it is compatible with Windows Vista,right?

Comment: There is primarily one reason why I had installed Git for Windows and then uninstalled it(that is obviously before I posted my problem here) -I watch Derek Banas tutorials on YouTube and

Comment: You see he uses a Mac-so uses TextWrangler and has downloaded Github for Mac from SourceForge

Comment: I'm unable to follow him because Git For Windows' interface is way different from his Mac's,and I need to learn Git commands and much more

Comment: Can you suggest a good tutorials that uses Git For Windows so I don't need to go through a lot of pain to understand and learn

Comment: yes, both tools run under Vista. here is a book about git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run PowerShell 3.0 on Windows Vista.

Microsoft Windows Vista is [out of mainstream support since April 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=11737&forceorigin=esmc)

PowerShell 3.0 was released in December 2012. It runs on (see the [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/windows-powershell-system-requirements) for details):

- Windows 8
- Windows Server 2012
- Windows 7 SP1
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
- Windows Server 2008 SP2

Comment: Then what do you suggest I do,to use git

Comment: Then it becomes a product request-question. If you want to have GUI interface have a few options available from [the official site](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis).

Comment: Just looked up your "the official site" link,and I want to know what am I looking at?

Comment: Do all of them consist of a git bash and work perfectly in sync with Github?